# Multiple Patterns in 1 case

Tags: sml, smlnj

In SML, is it possible for you to have multiple patterns in one case statement?

For example, I have 4 arithmetic operators express in string, `"+", "-", "*", "/"` and I want to print `"PLUS MINUS"` of it is `"+" or "-"` and `"MULT DIV"` if it is `"*" or "/"`.

TL;DR: Is there somewhere I can simplify the following to use less cases?

```
case str of
   "+" => print("PLUS MINUS")
 | "-" => print("PLUS MINUS")
 | "*" => print("MULT DIV")
 | "/" => print("MULT DIV")
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that you've tagged your question with the [smlnj](/questions/tagged/smlnj) tag, then yes, SML/NJ supports this kind of patterns. They call it [or-patterns](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/features.html) and it looks like this:

```
case str of
  ("+" | "-") => print "PLUS MINUS"
| ("*" | "/") => print "MULT DIV"
```

Notice the parentheses.

The master branch of MLton supports it too, as part of their [Successor ML effort](http://mlton.org/SuccessorML), but you'll have to compile MLton yourself.

```
val str = "+"

val _ =
  case str of
    "+" | "-" => print "PLUS MINUS"
  | "*" | "/" => print "MULT DIV"
```

Note that MLton does not require parantheses. Now compile it using this command (unlike SML/NJ, you have to enable this feature explicitly in MLton):

```
mlton -default-ann 'allowOrPats true' or-patterns.sml
```

Comment: Once you use that pattern, how do you access the character if you want to use it in the case? If you had the pattern x::xs you could say "The first is " ^ x. Could you say "The first is " ^ ("+ | "-")?

Comment: @retrovius you can bind it using an _as-pattern_: `char as ("+" | "-") => print ("char was: " ^ char ^ "\n")`.

Answer (score 2):

In Standard ML, no. In other dialects of ML, such as OCaml, yes. You may in some cases consider splitting pattern matching up into separate cases/functions, or skip pattern matching in favor of a shorter catch-all expression, e.g.

```
if str = "+" orelse str = "-" then "PLUS MINUS" else
if str = "*" orelse str = "/" then "MULT DIV" else ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding upon Ionuț's example, you can even use datatypes with other types in them, but their types (and identifier assignments) must match:

```
datatype mytype = COST as int | QUANTITY as int | PERSON as string | PET as string;

case item of
  (COST n|QUANTITY n) => print Int.toString n
  |(PERSON name|PET name) => print name
```

If the types or names don't match, it will get rejected:

```
case item of
  (COST n|PERSON n) => (* fails because COST is int and PERSON is string *)
  (COST n|QUANTITY q) => (* fails because the identifiers are different *)
```

And these patterns work in function definitions as well:

```
fun myfun (COST n|QUANTITY n) = print Int.toString n
   |myfun (PERSON name|PET name) = print name
;
```